# UnauthorizedException trying to use Windows TaskScheduler wrapper

Tags: c#, winapi, taskscheduler

I have the following code, which uses version 2.5.20 of David Hall's TaskScheduler Nuget package, that wraps the Windows Task Scheduler.  I'm trying to get all tasks from a specific folder, but for this question, let's just look at this code:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService(_ServerName, _TaskSchedulerUsername, _DomainName, _TaskSchedulerPassword)) {
    var folder = ts.GetFolder(TASK_FOLDER_NAME);
}
```

The `_TaskSchedulerUsername` and `_TaskSchedulerPassword` is a valid local account with admin priviledges; I used these credentials to open the Windows Task Scheduler and manually create a task, as a test, and was able to do so without problems.

`_ServerName` and `_DomainName` are the same, the local machine.

This code used to work as-is, and is currently running without issue on my test server (which is running Windows server 2003); it also runs on a production Windows 2012 Server box.  On my dev box (running Windows 10), I'm getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when I try to instantiate the new TaskService instance:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

The stack trace isn't very helpful:

```
at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.V2Interop.TaskSchedulerClass.Connect(Object serverName, Object user, Object domain, Object password)
at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService.Connect()
at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService.EndInit()
at Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService..ctor(String targetServer, String userName, String accountDomain, String password, Boolean forceV1)
at Test.TaskSchedulerServices.GetTaskSchedules() in C:\Projects\LE\dev\Test\Shared\Services\TaskSchedulerServices.svc.cs:line 54
```

Any ideas on why this won't run on my dev box, and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The Task Scheduler API changed significantly in Windows Vista. Your Server 2003 machine is on [v1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381811(v=vs.85).aspx), while the new Windows 10 machine is on [v2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381832(v=vs.85).aspx). In the case of v2, the NuGet package in question ends up calling [`ITaskScheduler::Connect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381833(v=vs.85).aspx). The documentation specifies that you can simply leave the server name null to connect to the local machine. (That should work for v1's [`SetTargetComputer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381831(v=vs.85).aspx) as well.) The domain should be set to the computer's name if you're specifying a local user's name.

Though if you just want to connect to the local machine as the current user, you can just use the `TaskService` constructor that takes no parameters.

Comment: This might solve someone else's problem, but I tried swapping the _ServerName parameter for null and I'm still getting the exact same error. Also, didn't mention in the original question, but this exact same code has been running on a production Windows 2012 server for some time without issue as well.